# How to create an ajax request by compare with times in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm want to request a content by using Ajax request with comparison between current time and with  argument (data) to check as IF conditional in getresult function .

I want to use `getresult` to check if my argument (data) is equal to `1800` and `1300` time in `startTimes()` function. So if my conditional is pass I will call an ajax and stop.

**My issue** My ajax will request 119 times when my `getresult` meet it conditional.

Do anyone have any better function to build this feature please help me.

```
startTimes();

function checkTimes(i) {
    return i;
}

function startTimes() {

    var today = new Date(),
            h = today.getHours(),
            m = today.getMinutes(),
            s = today.getSeconds();
    var t = h + '' + m;

    setTimeout(function () {
        startTimes();
    }, 500);
    getresult(t);
}

function getresult(data) {

    if (data == 1800) {
//        Ajax request here
    }if(data == 1300){
//        Ajax request here
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it gets called 119 `(actually is 120)` times because you are calling the function every 500 miliseconds and before a minute is passed the time still is 1800 or 1300 depending the case.

so, to be more specific `120 * 500 = 60000 miliseconds or 1 minute`, by that time the comparison is diferent. you can change the timeout time to be one minute check, try this:

```
//Run every minute
setInterval(function() {
    startTimes();
}, 60000);    //1000 milliseconds * 60 seconds

function startTimes() {
  var date = new Date();
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();

  //call ajax at 18:00
  if(hours == 18 && minutes == 0) {
    //ajax request here
  }
  //call ajax at 13:00
  if(hours == 13 && minutes == 0) {
    //ajax request here
  }
}
```

Comment: I did it do you have another function which better than this one

Comment: I Don't understand what do you want to change?